# Produto entre escalar e array

Tags: python, numpy

Eu tenho um vetor:

```
a = [0.4850045, 0.45512111]
```

e um vetor de um elemento:

```
b = [-0.03116616]
```

Estou tentando multiplicar o conteúdo do vetor `b`, ou seja, `b[0]`, pelo vetor `a`, mas ao invés de obter :

```
b[0] * a == [-0.01511573, -0.01418438]
```

estou obtendo:

```
b[0] * a == [[-0.01511573, -0.01418438]
             [-0.01511573, -0.01418438]]
```

Segue um exemplo completo do problema que estou enfrentando:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.3], [-0.1]])
b = np.zeros(a.shape)
c = np.array([0.5249765])
d = np.array([0.4850045, 0.45512111])
y = np.array([0.4])
error = y - c 
f = error * c * (1 - c)

b += f[0] * d.T
```

O resultado é o seguinte erro:

> *ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (2,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (2,2)*

Comment: Está utilizando alguma biblioteca, tipo NumPy?

Comment: Já experimentou `b = b + f[0]*d.T` ?

Comment: Já isac, funciona mas o resultado é uma matriz (2,2) e preciso que seja (2,1)

Comment: Você diz que `b[0] * a` não retorna o resultado que você espera, porém o [retorno é o esperado](https://repl.it/@fernandosavio/SOPt-395418-6333), seu problema não é onde você diz que é, mas sim em outro lugar do seu _exemplo completo_ (que deveria ser um [mcve]).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode se utilizar de um laço para realizar a operação, como exemplo, segue um algoritmo com laço for e com a aplicação do método enumerate:

```
a = [ 0.4850045, 0.45512111]
b = [-0.03116616]

for i, j in enumerate(a):
    a[i] = j*b[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Se você desejar resolver esta questão utilizando a biblioteca `numpy`, pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0.4850045, 0.45512111])
b = np.array([-0.03116616])

prod = (a * b)

print(f'O produto escalar é: {prod}')
```

Ao executar este algoritmo o resultado será...

```
[-0.01511573 -0.01418438]
```

Answer (score 0):

Caso não queira utilizar **numpy** você pode resolver com list comprehension:

```py
a = [0.4850045, 0.45512111]
b = [-0.03116616]

[(x * y) for x in a for y in b]
```

Saída:

```py
[-0.015115727847719999, -0.0141843773336376]
```